# How to mitigate "flickering" of thin elements in a image/texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

The title might sound a bit confusing, but I don't want to make it too long, so please bear with me and read on...

I'm writing a very simple OpenGL demo that loads an image as texture, then scrolls the image horizontally across the screen infinitely. Here's how I load the texture and render a single frame:

```
void load_texture(char* filename)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl_texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filename, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

void render_single_frame()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_texture);
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            float delta = fmod(1.0f / FRAME_RATE / pan_seconds * current_frame, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f + delta, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f + delta, 0.0f); glVertex2f(+1.0f, -1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f + delta, 1.0f); glVertex2f(+1.0f, +1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f + delta, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, +1.0f);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFinish();
    current_frame++;
}
```

...where `FRAME_RATE` is the target frame rate and `pan_seconds` is the seconds it should take to scroll across an entire image.

Overall the demo runs quite well, but to nitpick I crafted a test image containing very thin elements - some thin texts and a 1-pixel-wide vertical line (on the very right) on a black background.

[image: Test image]

When this image is fed into the demo, and when `pan_seconds` is high (i.e. image scrolls slowly), the problem emerges - all these elements would noticeably flicker (fluctuate in brightness), most obviously present for the vertical line.

My analysis is that the high `pan_seconds` results in fractional `delta`s, i.e. subpixel movements, and OpenGL would have to filter the texture to determine the color of a pixel. Take the vertical line as an example, the interpolation of Bilinear filtering (`GL_LINEAR`) will for most of the time produce a 2-pixel-wide *gray* line, which the human eye perceives as 1-pixel-wide, but at the same time will appear less bright compared to the original *white* line.

This doesn't help with solving the problem though... Changing filter mode to `GL_NEAREST` will break the smooth scrolling effect; changing to `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` does eliminate the flicker, but at the cost of significantly blurring the image, which is not an acceptable outcome.

Is there a way to reduce this flickering without losing much sharpness, or do I have to trust my own theoretical analysis and call it impossible?

Comment: You could "round" the coordinates to full pixel coordinates before rendering.

Comment: Make sure your texture actually has mips. Also, for text rendering, you could use distance field (look for Valve whitepaper)

Comment: What would you expect the thin line on the right to do? Should it "jump" from pixel to pixel as with `GL_NEAREST` or should it be "blurred" between two adjacent pixels? It seems you are dismissing both options, it's not clear what you expect the pixels on the screen to actually display. Note that this is not an easy problem and requires subpixel rendering for best results (which in turn requires you to know how the color pixels are arranged on the physical screen). Take for example [ClearType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes I expected it to "jump" from pixel to pixel. `GL_NEAREST` doesn't actually do that though - it causes the line's width to constantly vary between 1 and 2 pixels, which looks terrible. I'm not even sure why it happens, since the image used is of the same resolution as the display and in my opinion no filtering should occur at all.

Comment: @BDL That seems to work despite how simple it sounds, at very high framerate and resolution the rounding error is kinda negligible. I'll let whoever assigned me this task evaluate if it's good enough (if it is, you should post an answer). Thanks for the swift response!

Comment: @AndyYan: If you round the coordinates passed to `glVertex2f` instead of delta, then rounding errors are always below 1 pixel size (but that's exactly what you asked for), but they don't accumulate over frames.

Comment: @BDL The assigner approved of the end result and gave me further instructions, and while the new requirements mean I'll be calculating delta in another way, the simple idea of limiting delta to multiples of pixel width still applies and helps greatly. If you put it into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You could work with coordinates equal to pixels, e.g.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-w/2.f, +w/2.f, -h/2.f, h/2.f, ZNEARCLIP * -1.f, ZFARCLIP * -1.f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
```

If you now draw a line when x and y are whole numbers, the line should end up 1 px wide and not spanned over 2 pixels with interpolation.

Comment: It's not what OP asked about.

Comment: He asked for "a way to reduce this flickering without losing much sharpness". This is one way to do it. Feel free to post your own solution though.